# Problem while installing Qogir theme in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: themes, 19.04

I have installed ubuntu 19.04 and now tried to install Quogir theme
from `https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/install-the-qogir-gtk-theme-on-linux/`. After downloading and installing it, I tried to install the images through `./Install -i` command which is asking root permission. But after putting root password, it is showing somthing like this:

```
jagannath@jagannath:~/Qogir-theme$ ./Install -i
\n sassc needs to be installed to generate the css.
[ trusted ] specify the root password : \n running: sudo apt install sassc 
Reading package lists... Done: 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libsass1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsass1 sassc
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 773 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,753 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
\n Operation canceled  Bye
```

Now, I can see the Qogir themes in my gnome-tweak but the background images are missing. Please give your suggestion about this problem.

Comment: Are you using GNOME (default for 19.04) or UNITY as your desktop?   `unity-tweak-tool` should be used if using Unity, and `gnome-tweaks` if using Gnome.

Comment: yes, I am using GNOME as my desktop hence, gnome-tweaks.

Comment: it worked for me but I couldn't get the gnome part : `./Install -m gnome
ERROR: Unrecognized installation option '-m'.`

Comment: but seeing as it doesn't appear in the help i think they just made installing with gnome compatibility default since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the required package by:

`sudo apt install sassc`

After that try again to install downloaded theme.

Comment: That fixed my problem, thank you!